# IPv6 gateway to IPv4 address

Tags: server, ipv6, vps, ipv4, gateway

I am looking for a gateway service to transform an IPv6 address to an IPv4. I have a VPS connected to an IPv6 Network but my ISP is on IPv4. So I can't (or don't know how) connect via SSH to my VPS server.
I will appreciate any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a client machine on an ipv4-only network and you want to ssh into a machine on an ipv6-only network.

There are a few options.

1. 6to4, works automatically through relays found by internet routing. 6to4 gateway machine must have a public IPv4 address. ipv6 address block is derived from ipv4 address. Relays are sometimes overloaded leading to poor performance.
2. teredo, works through relays found by internet routing but requires a configured server for connection setup. Several operators run free public teredo servers. Works from behind most NATs. Can be a bit fragile and relays are often overloaded.
3. configured point to point tunnels either free or paid for. Well-known free operators include Hurricane Electric and gogo6. Free tunnels may have restrictions on allowed protocols and/or poor performance.

Comment: 6to4 and Teredo are so bad that they have been deprecated these days. A Hurricane Electric tunnel is your best bet. Well, actually getting your ISP to do its job and provide you with production quality IPv6 is what is the real solution.